# Invalid appsecret_proof - why?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

So, I'm building a new app, using the Javascript API to log in (v2.4), and the latest version (v5) of the PHP API. I created a Test App for it, and am working with that. Using the Javascript API, I do the login and authentication, and save the access token that I get back from getLoginStatus:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { 
    handleLoginStatusChange(response); 
});

function handleLoginStatusChange(response)
{
    . . .
    else if (response.status == 'connected')  
    {
        // make ajax call to save access token
    . . .
}
```

Then, inside my PHP code, I pick up that access token, and try to use it. I calculate an appsecret_proof, as well.:

```
$this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                           'app_id'    => <my app id>,
                           'app_secret'=> <my app secret>,
                           'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3'
                                  ]);
$this->fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp( <my app id>, 
                                         <my app secret );

$appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', <access token>, 
                                       <app secret>);
```

Then I try to post a link to my FB account:

```
$linkData = [
             'link' => 'https://google.com',
             'message' => 'This is a test post',
            ];
$response = $this->fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, <access token>);
```

This gives me the dreaded " Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument" error. I don't know if this is the problem, but if I put the access token into the debugger, it tells me that this access token is for my actual app, not my test app, so the appID's don't match. I don't think that's a problem, if I understand test apps, especially because I am using the test appID and test appSecret all through this code.

Any ideas? I see several things here on StackOverflow, but they either are older versions of the API, or talk of editing the API code itself to disable things.

Answer (score 0):

> it tells me that this access token is for my actual app, not my test app, so the appID's don't match

That is why it does not work.

Think about what happens on Facebook’s side: They need the app secret that was used to calculate the app-secret proof, so they have to look that up via the app id. And where do they get that app id from? From the access token …!

So if you pass an access token for a different app, that will make them use the wrong app secret to calculate the app-secret proof – and so it will not match the value that you sent.

**You need to use an access token that belongs to your test app.**

(And the PHP SDK takes care of calculating and sending the app secret proof itself, you don’t need to handle that manually.)

Comment: Whew... pointed to my problem. Wound up using the wrong variable in my fB.init... so I got the wrong access token. Ok, now I just have to fix the actual post, but now I'm not getting the error. Thanks!